# The fastest way to display a pixel-raster on iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, opengl-es

I'm wondering what's the fastest way to render a pixel-raster from memory onto the screen of iOS devices, to achieve the highest possible framerate. I can figure two approaches:

1. Create a CGImage with CGImageCreate, draw that onto the screen with CGContextDrawImage in the drawRect method and then delete the CGImage-object
2. Use OpenGL in orthographic mode, copy the pixels into a texture with glTexImage2D and render a quad with that texture

Probably the second approach will be faster than the first. But will it be significant faster or just a little bit? And is there a third way of doing it, which will be faster than the first two I mentioned?

Comment: So is calling the glTexImage2D method for every frame the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

If your image is updating frequently, creating a texture every frame (or nearly every frame) will be quite a performance hit. You might have better luck using a `CALayer` and settings its [contents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW24) property to a `CGImageRef` you wish to use. The result will be similar to using `CGContextDrawImage()` how you described, but provides Core Animation more flexibility in rendering, hopefully making it faster.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Will setting the contents property to a CGImageRef immediately display the image or do I have to call some kind of redraw method?

Comment: I think you'll have to call `-[CALayer setNeedsDisplay]` after changing the contents in order to trigger a redraw. Even if not strictly necessary, it'll only update if necessary, so there should be no associated performance hit.